# Check when package update was rolled out

Tags: package-management, repository

I need to know when a package was updated, not on my machine but on the repository. What I'd like to see is a "history" of all versions of a given package on the repository together with the dates when it was updated (for Ubuntu 16.04), is it possible? Thank you.